How to serve file content in response?
I want base64 pdf to be in response. I am able to store it in file. Still I would like to make it in response json data to load from file or other way to upload file into data element of json from response.
My response looks like this
    "data": "JVBERi0xLjcNCiWhs8X..." //how to get this string from my file, or to decode my file into this place of response?

Any suggestion how to get anything into response from file are welcomed as I am new to Mackoon.

Best solution I found is by let finalString=startJson+base64str+endJson
and then generated json could be uploaded in [Status & Body] -> File tab.
This will not support of inline response so it's more like walkaround. But in my case this is good enough solution.
